# Show Apps and Activities Overview are laggy

Tags: activities-overview

When i use activities overview or show apps its so much laggy and takes around 4-5 seconds to load up. How can i fix this?

Btw i am using Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E6500  @2.93GHz processor with 4 gb ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unable ui animations on Settings/Accessibility/Enable Animations. Switch off this option. Not sure, but graphics capacities of your computers will be not enought to run properly Gnome. You can try Xubuntu.

[Animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEIoG.png)